# Error to deploy a silverlight application in IIS6: Invalid or malformed application: Check manifest

Tags: silverlight, deployment

Folks, I deploy a silverlight application on windows server 2008 (IIS7) and ran ok, no errors.

I put this same application on another server with windows server 2003, IIS 6, with the mime types configured, asp.net 4, etc. But when I try to run it I get the error: Invalid or malformed application: Check manifest

I checked on google, but the attempts were unsuccessful. Anyone out there have any idea what might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these links might help you
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/262/configuring-iis-for-silverlight-applications/ 
http://geekswithblogs.net/SoftwareDoneRight/archive/2010/01/09/how-to-host-silverlight-apps-under-iis6.aspx

Comment: Hey Daniel, thanks guy. My problem was that I was changing the file. xap directly, to change the port of ServiceReference.ClientConfig. I started to change the port before publishing the file .xap and error is over. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

check for the startup object name in the silverlight project properties

Comment: Hello friend. Thanks for the anser, but I saw and try it, with no sucess, because I didn't change the namespace of app. Any other suggestion?

Comment: what is the silverlight ver you are working on and what is the name of your xap file?

Comment: Silverlight 4 and the xap name is: GedLumenSilverlight.xap

Comment: see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793877/silverlight-application-doesnt-run-i-get-an-invalid-or-malformed-application-er) can be any help to you

Comment: Subhash, I created a new project web with silverlight project. I have instaled it in a server with II7 and I have no errors, works fine. Now I need to run in a windows server 2003 with II6. I have configured mime types, asp.net 4, and etc. My service is working fine. What can be?

Comment: are you using asp.net security options like authentication/authorisation for the folders if so check permission for the clientbin folder

Comment: I got full permission to everyone on the application folder (include clientbin), but I got the same error.