# Internet Explorer fails to run Silverlight Apps after BitDefender 2013 Install

Tags: silverlight, antivirus

I have no idea what's happening here. All I know is that my silverlight web apps ran perfectly after being deployed in December, and now when I open my project and run it it dies with the check manifest error:

Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 2103
Category: InitializeError
Message: Invalid or malformed application: Check manifest

I know that silly error, and trust me, I didn't change anything (no names, no namespaces, nothing)

A bit of fiddling in fiddler shows that the following 2 files cannot be found each time the app is loading:

/B1D671CF-E532-4481-99AA-19F420D90332/netdefender/hui/ndhui.css

and

/B1D671CF-E532-4481-99AA-19F420D90332/netdefender/hui/ndhui.js?0=0&0=0&0=0

I am not familiar with those files, and in no area of my app am I reffering to them. I am now wondering if the recent installation of BitDefender 2013 has anything to do with it, or maybe it could be the recent windows update that updated the .NET framework 4.0. I tried editing the anti Phishing feature in fact I turned off all the features in BitDefender with nothing availing. If anyone knows what to do regarding this, I would be most thankful for a tip.

Comment: Surely you can dream up a more-descriptive title.

Comment: Not really, since I couldn't imagine what was wrong, even while dreaming. However, what I am sure about now is that those 2 files are definately associated with BitDefender. Question is, how do I stop this madness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well then, I was right after all; BitDefender was at fault. I finally made up my mind and decided to uninstall bitDefender 2013. So I ran the BitDefender Uninstall tool I used to uninstall bitDefender 2012. It seemed to have gone through the process ok, then as expected asked for a restart to complete uninstallation. I didn't realize that only the uninstall tool specifically made for bitDefender 2013 could uninstall it. So, after restart bitDefender 2013 was still present and running perfectly. However, the difference now was that visual studio had no problem debugging my applications neither my browsers any problem loading my Silverlight apps either locally or externally.

Weird? Believe it.

Answer (score 0):

From error code 2103, it seems that there is an issue with manifest file. Most probably you have changed namespace. Here are 4 links that might be helpful.

[MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alvarod/archive/2010/11/14/error-unhandled-error-in-silverlight-application-code-2103-category-initializeerror-message-invalid-or-malformed-application-check-manifest.aspx)

[One More MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/narend/archive/2009/10/21/silverlight-3-error-unhandled-error-in-silverlight-application-code-2103-category-initializeerror-message-invalid-or-malformed-application-check-manifest.aspx)

[Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/393604/Error-2103-Unhandled-Error-in-Silverlight-Applicat)

[StackOverflow Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793877/silverlight-application-doesnt-run-i-get-an-invalid-or-malformed-application-e)

Comment: Thanks Manoj, but as stated before; I am sure I didn't change anything. Another point though, just before the error window pops up in the browser I get a dialog in fiddler that states: Content-Length mismatch: Response Header indicated 8,026,658 bytes, but server sent 7,797,698 bytes.