# Silverlight 5 (5.1.30214.0) causes "Invalid or malformed application" error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, silverlight-5.0

I recently updated Silverlight to version 5.1.30214.0 and am now seeing this strange error:

```
Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application
Code: 2103
Category: InitializeError
Message: Invalid or malformed application: Check manifest
```

I already checked the following (see [Silverlight application doesn't run. I get an invalid or malformed application error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793877/silverlight-application-doesnt-run-i-get-an-invalid-or-malformed-application-e)):

- I did not make any namespace changes
- startup object is set correctly
- I do not use any styles
- I do not use any resources
- generated AppManifest contains correct EntryPoint and AssemblyParts
- uninstalled and re-installed Silverlight 5 and SDK

I also recreated the whole Silverlight project (different namespace) and manually recreated the files.

Anything I'm missing?

**UPDATE:**
I manually removed all files under *bin* and *obj* and recompiled (Clean option does not seem to work). It now appears to be working again?!

Comment: Happened to me once. Upgrading SL made the bin/obj folders corrupted and VS was not deleting them.

Answer (score 0):

As silly as it might seem, VS-2012 does **NOT** clean the bin/obj folders. Deleting the files manually fixed the issue and everything is hunky dory again.

I wasted hours on this. Hopefully this will help someone out there.